# rewrite sql query without using union in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I would appreciate some help to write an equivalent query.

I have the following table:

```
+------+----------+---------------+
|  id  | group_id | question_body |
+------+----------+---------------+
| 1001 |      101 | q1            |
| 1002 |      101 | q2            |
| 1003 |      102 | q3            |
| 1004 |      103 | q4            |
| 1005 |      103 | q5            |
| 1006 |      104 | q6            |
| 1007 |      105 | q6            |
| 2001 |      201 | q7            |
| 2002 |      202 | q8            |
| 2003 |      203 | q9            |
| 2004 |      204 | q10           |
| 2005 |      204 | q11           |
| 2006 |      204 | q12           |
| 2007 |      204 | q13           |
| 2008 |      205 | q14           |
| 3001 |      301 | q16           |
| 3002 |      301 | q17           |
| 3003 |      302 | q18           |
| 3004 |      302 | q19           |
| 3005 |      303 | q20           |
| 3006 |      304 | q21           |
| 3007 |      305 | q22           |
| 3008 |      305 | q23           |
| 3009 |      305 | q24           |
+------+----------+---------------+
```

by using a series of queries with UNION in between, I get to the exact result I need but I CAN NOT use UNION :(

So my query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 101 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) as g101

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 102 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g102

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 103 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g103

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 104 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g104

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 105 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g105

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 201 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) as g201

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 202 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g202

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 203 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g203

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 204 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g204

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 205 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g205

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 301 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) as g301

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 302 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g302

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 303 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g303

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 304 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g304

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  questions.id FROM questions WHERE questions.group_id LIKE 305 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) AS g305
;
```

This goes by each `group_id` and randomly selects a question attached to that group. Is there a more simple way to write this with NO `UNION`?

Comment: Your current approach is a common way to handle this in MySQL.  Why can't you use unions?

Comment: This is an exercice for me. So I did not asked why 

Comment: Sidenote: insted `LIKE` use `=`.

Comment: Assuming that the code works correctly, you might want to write up your samples in a more-complete fashion and ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Comment: You can do it horizontally (i.e. using columns) without unions. Is that an option? Simply convert them to subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
select g.*,
       (select q.id
        from questions q
        where q.group_id = g.group_id
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) as question_id
from groups g;
```

Selecting one random row per group is not difficult.  Multiple rows is trickier.

This assumes you have a table called `groups`. If not, you can use `from (select distinct group_id from questions) g`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to use this to get forward in my exercises!